# telephone directory update issue

Tags: php, mysql

I was programming something and I faced the problem. I was wondering where is the problem, because my code stop working after mysql_query("UPDATE ...") part. Here is the code, I hope someone will help me.

```
<?php include("/includes/template/header.php"); ?>

        <section>

            <form action="" method="post">
                <input type="post" name="ime" placeholder="Ime"><br>
                <input type="post" name="prezime" placeholder="Prezime"><br>
                <input type="post" name="broj" placeholder="Broj telefona"><br>
                <input type="post" name="adresa" placeholder="Adresa"><br>
                <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Trazi">
            </form>

            <?php

                include("includes/config.php");

                if(isset($_POST['submit']))
                {
                    if(!empty($_POST['ime']) && !empty($_POST['prezime']))
                    {
                        $trazeno_ime     =  $_POST['ime'];
                        $trazeno_prezime =  $_POST['prezime'];

                        $query = "SELECT id, broj_telefona, adresa FROM korisnici WHERE ime = '$trazeno_ime' AND prezime='$trazeno_prezime'";

                        if ($query_run = mysql_query($query)) 
                        {

                            if(mysql_num_rows($query_run)!=NULL) 
                                {
                                    $query_row = mysql_fetch_assoc($query_run);
                                    $id        = $query_row["id"];
                                    $brojtel   = $query_row["broj_telefona"];
                                    $adresa    = $query_row["adresa"];

                                    echo "<form action=\"\" method=\"post\">";
                                    echo "<input type=\"post\" name=\"ime1\" value=\"$trazeno_ime\"><br></br>";
                                    echo "<input type=\"post\" name=\"prezime1\" value=\"$trazeno_prezime\"><br></br>";
                                    echo "<input type=\"post\" name=\"broj1\" value=\"$brojtel\"><br></br>";
                                    echo "<input type=\"post\" name=\"adresa1\" value=\"$adresa\"><br></br>";
                                    echo "<input type=\"submit\" name=\"submit1\" value=\"Promijeni\">";
                                    echo "</form>";

                                        if(isset($_POST['submit1']))
                                        {
                                            if(!empty($_POST['ime1']) && !empty($_POST['prezime1']) && !empty($_POST['broj1']) && !empty($_POST['broj1']) && !empty($_POST['adresa']))
                                            {
                                                $novoime        =   $_POST['ime1'];
                                                $novoprezime    =   $_POST['prezime1'];
                                                $novobroj       =   $_POST['broj1'];
                                                $novoadresa     =   $_POST['adresa1'];

                                                mysql_query("UPDATE korisnici SET ime='$novoime', prezime='$novoprezime', broj_telefona='$novobroj', adresa='$novoadresa' WHERE id=$id") or die(mysql_error());

                                                echo "Uspješno promijenjeni podaci";
                                            }
                                            else
                                            {
                                                echo "Morate unijeti sva polja";
                                            }
                                        }
                                        else
                                        {
                                            echo "Glupost";
                                        }
                                } 
                            else 
                            {

                                echo "Nema korisnika u bazi";

                            }

                        } 
                        else 
                        {
                            echo "Hahu";
                        }

                    }
                    else
                    {
                        echo "Unesi podatke";
                    }
                }

            ?>

        </section>

    </div>
</body>
```

Comment: You are vulnerable to [sql injection attacks](http://bobby-tables.com), and should not be using the mysql_*() functions anymore. They're obsolete and deprecated.

Comment: Warning
mysql_query is deprecated as of PHP 5.5.0, and will be removed in the future. Instead, the MySQLi or PDO_MySQL extension should be used

Answer (score 0):

You need to add quotes to your id statement see below.

```
"UPDATE korisnici SET ime='$novoime', prezime='$novoprezime', broj_telefona='$novobroj', adresa='$novoadresa' WHERE id='$id'"
```